# DataBinding in android and MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, android-databinding

I can see that Data binding library is added with Android M which is still in beta release. But how to achieve MVC with Data binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your core components and techniques for implementing MVC won't change. How to implement MVC in general is not bound to databinding in this case.

The advantage of using the databinding library is transferring a lot of repetitive controller code to the databinding API, i.e. setting text-values and -styles or event handlers.

Did you read through this thoroughly?
https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html

You can still implement your Activity-class' controller code as usual. In addition you have Auto-Generated Binding-instances, whose values you can set, causing an automated Ui-Update.

Remarks:
You probably don't want separate event handler classes implementing the handler code.
Using some DesignPatterns you can create event-forwarding-classes for the event-handler bindings, to have the handler implementation within the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Data binding is only related to bind data which will to some extend decrease you findViewById it. It will give you the flexibility to bind data in xml itself.
MVC will work as the same but you can make it more robust with data binding.

More over you can also go through MVP and dagger implementation also
https://github.com/JesusM/MVPDaggerAndroid